# on ("click") not working with d3 circle

Tags: d3.js

I am unable to get the click to work on the circle. I have read various tips about how to attach clicks etc. to circles but I cannot get them to work so I must not understand them.

Any tips would be appreciated.

```
d3.json("d3_files/json/points-category-xyz.json",function(error,data){
  svg.select("#points")
 .selectAll("circle")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("circle")
 .attr("r",10)
 .style("fill-opacity",.7)
 .style("display",function(data){
    return"block";
  }) // end display style
 .style("fill",function (data) {
    if (data.category=="abc") {
      return "blue"
    } // endif
    else {
      return "red"
    } // endelse
  }) // end style fill
 .style("stroke","#fff")
 .on("click", function (){ // this doesn't appear to work
   console.log("Hmmm");
   alert("Hello");
  }) // end click
 .attr("transform",function(data){
    return"translate("+projection([data.lng,data.lat])+")"
  }) // end transform attr

.on("mouseout",function(d){
 d3.select("body")
  .select(".datamaps-hoverover")
  .style("display","none");  
 d3.select(this)
  .style("stroke-width","1px")
  }) // end mouseout
 .on("mouseover",function(d){
 d3.select(this)
   .style("stroke-width","4px")
   .html(function() {
       return node.attributes.name.value + "Popup here"
    }) // end .html
}) // end mouseover
.on("mousemove",function(data){
 var data=d3.mouse(this);
var n=this;
d3.select(this)
  .style("stroke-width","4px")
  d3.select("body") 
    .select(".datamaps-hoverover")
    .style("display","block")
    .style("top",data[1]+10+"px")
    .html(function() {
       return node.attributes.name.value + "Popup here"
     }) // end html
     .style("left",data[0]+"px")
}) // end mouseover
}); // end points json
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it doesn't work? Do any of the other handlers work?

Comment: It does nothing ... it doesn't display an alert or write to the log ... none of the other handlers work either, However if I attach the handler to a <p> tag it works.

Comment: Is everything else working correctly? Could you post a complete example please?

Comment: I adapted another chart and there may be code that isn't being used. The map of Toronto is drawn correctly and I have placed two circles on it. However, clicking on the circles does nothing.

Comment: Are you drawing the map or the circles first?

Comment: I believe I am drawing the map first ... at least it is before the code for the circles (but as you can tell I am not an expert in this.) I tried to post the code but it was too long.

Comment: Are the circles on top of the map, i.e. are they getting pointer events at all?

Comment: Maybe not ... I just realized that when I run the script the circles draw first and then the map. How do I control that?

Comment: Move the code to draw the circles after the code that does the map.

Comment: The code that draws the circles is the last code in the script. Is there something else that could affect the order?

Comment: Yes, you probably have an asynchronous call somewhere. Can't really help you with this without having seen the entire code though.

Comment: I've posted the full code to one of my sites: http://zerocarbonontario.ca/d3-script - thanks very much for your patience

Comment: Ok, you probably want two separate `g` elements for that -- `var paths = svg.append("g"), circles = svg.append("g");` and then use those as root for `.selectAll(...)` in the respective callbacks instead of `svg`.

Comment: Wow! I really had to do a bit of translating (in my head) because you used terms I was not familiar with but it worked. Many thanks.

Comment: Ok cool. I'll post that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your circles are obscured by other elements and never receive pointer events. One solution to fix this is to append the circles last.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
link.on("click", function(d){
   $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.show(d);
   });
   d3.event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: AJT. Why did u downvote? It was only answer and correct answer.